# Why sys.path.insert not using the latest python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, sys, pythonpath

List below is my project structure.

```
├── folder1
    ├── test.py
├── folder2
    ├── A.py
├── folder3
    ├── A.py
```

`A.py` in `folder2` and `folder3` are the same except `self.key`

```
#folder2
class TestAPI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = 50 


#folder3
class TestAPI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = 100
```

In `test.py`, the code is

```
import sys
root_path = '/user/my_account'

sys.path.insert(0, root_path + '/folder2')
from A import TestAPI
test_api =  TestAPI()
print(test_api.key)

sys.path.insert(0, root_path + '/folder3')
from A import TestAPI
test_api = TestAPI()
print(test_api.key)
print(sys.path)
```

While executing `test.py`, it returns `50`,`50`, `['/user/my_account/folder3', '/user/my_account/folder2']`. Why the second time `from A import TestAPI` not from `folder3` but  `folder2`?

Edit: If I'd like to `import TestAPI` from `folder3` for the second time, is there a way to 'delete' the `PYTHONPATH`  after `import TestAPI` from `folder2`?

Comment: Python searches your PYTHONPATH in a certain order, and I believe it just stops after the first find. Thus, it's not even thinking about `folder3`. Having the same codename will be confusing and with relative imports you will lose track. Given the similarities in code, I suggest that you just have one code and allow for an input so `self.key = key`. I'm providing an answer below for how to do this since it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`importlib.reload` solve my question.

```
import sys
root_path = '/user/my_account'

sys.path.insert(0, root_path + '/folder2')
import A
test_api =  A.TestAPI()
print(test_api.key)

sys.path.insert(0, root_path + '/folder3')
import importlib
importlib.reload(A)  # should reload after inserting PYTHONPATH and before import A

import A
test_api = A.TestAPI()
print(test_api.key)
print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `TestAPI` code (A.py) into a commons folder (one that can be imported by other codes) and then have:

```
class TestAPI():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
```

Then in your test.py you can do something like:

```
import sys
root_path = '/user/my_account'

sys.path.insert(0, root_path + '/commons')
from commons.A import TestAPI

test_api_50 =  TestAPI(50)
print(test_api_50.key)

test_api_100 = TestAPI(100)
print(test_api_100.key)
```

I can edit this if there's an issue/typo.

Note that python folder/packaging is worth reading about. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: Thanks @astrochun. The reason why I ask this is I had the same issue in my study. And I just make it simple to understand. In your answer, you import TestAPI for one time. Which is very different from my case.

Comment: Yes, but you said it's the same but one difference, so you should refactor that. Then you won't be confused about which A.py you're using. You just have one that is generalized.

Comment: I can refactor in my question. However, there are occasions where we have the same things in two different name folders.

Answer (score -1):

sys.path is a list.  So just use the append method.

Also, you don't need root path. just run

```
sys.path.append('folder2')
```

Edit: demo that prooves that it works

```
[luca@artix stackoverflow]$ mkdir my_module
[luca@artix stackoverflow]$ ed my_module/foo.py
?my_module/foo.py
i
print('From foo')
.
wq
18
[luca@artix stackoverflow]$ python
Python 3.9.1 (default, Feb  6 2021, 13:49:29) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('my_module')
>>> import foo
From foo
>>>
```

Comment: Have you try your answer?

Comment: I used it in some binary tree scripts lol